# Loopback.js - How do I pass multiple parameters to model remote method

Tags: node.js, api, loopbackjs

I'm trying to change a remote method for the Idioma model which only had one parameter (id). This is is the actual functioning code:

```
Model.remoteMethod('idiomaByOferta', {
  description: 'Obtener un idioma por oferta',
  http: { path: '/oferta/:id', verb: 'get' },
  accepts: [
    { arg: 'id', type: 'string', required: true },
    { arg: 'res', type: 'object', http: { source: 'res' } }
  ],
  returns: {
    type: 'Object',
    root: true,
    default: output_structure
  }
});

Model.idiomaByOferta = (id, res, cb) => {
  parameterValidatorId(id, err => {
    if (err) {
      res.status(httpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.code).send(err);
    }
  });
  const conn = Model.app.datasources.db.connector;
  commons
    .getResultSqlString(conn, sqlEstablecimiento.findIdiomas, [id])
    .then(stb => {
      cb(null, stb);
    })
    .catch(err => cb(err, null));
  };

Model.afterRemote('idiomaByOferta', async (ctx, result, next) => {
  delete ctx.res.req.query.limit;
  delete ctx.res.req.query.page;
  delete query.limit;
  delete query.page;
  next();
});
```

Now I want to include another parameter but I haven't found exactly how to do it with required parameters. I have tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
Model.remoteMethod('idiomaByOferta', {
  description: 'Obtener un idioma por oferta',
  http: { path: '/oferta', verb: 'get' },
  accepts: [
    { arg: 'id', type: 'string', required: true, http: { source: 'query' }},
    { arg: 'nivel', type: 'string', required: true, http: { source: 'query' }},
    { arg: 'res', type: 'object', http: { source: 'res' } }
  ],
  returns: {
    type: 'Object',
    root: true,
    default: output_structure
  }
});
```

Request url: {{url}}/api/idiomas/oferta?id={{oferta}}&nivel=Inicial

Response:

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "code": 938,
            "source": "id",
            "detail": "is not allowed"
        },
        {
            "code": 963,
            "source": "nivel",
            "detail": "is not allowed"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have also tried doing this:

```
Model.remoteMethod('idiomaByOferta', {
  description: 'Obtener un idioma por oferta',
  http: { path: '/oferta/:id/nivel/:nivel', verb: 'get' },
  accepts: [
    { arg: 'id', type: 'string', required: true},
    { arg: 'nivel', type: 'string', required: true},
    { arg: 'res', type: 'object', http: { source: 'res' } }
  ],
  returns: {
    type: 'Object',
    root: true,
    default: output_structure
  }
});
```

The request times out and is never completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The position of your `accepts` attributes is important.

In your `http` attribute, the argument `path` is optionnal and is useful if you want to change the order of your `accepts` attributes or simply modify the path name.

What I would do is:

```
Model.remoteMethod('idiomaByOferta', {
  description: 'Obtener un idioma por oferta',
  http: { path: '/oferta/:id/:nivel', verb: 'get' },
  accepts: [
    { arg: 'id', type: 'string', required: true },
    { arg: 'nivel', type: 'string', required: true},
    { arg: 'res', type: 'object', http: { source: 'res' } }
  ],
  returns: {
    type: 'Object',
    root: true,
    default: output_structure
  }
});

Model.idiomaByOferta = (id, nivel, res, cb) => { //add nivel here in second position
  parameterValidatorId(id, err => {
    if (err) {
      res.status(httpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.code).send(err);
    }
  });
  parameterValidatorId(nivel, err => {
    if (err) {
      res.status(httpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.code).send(err);
    }
  });
  const conn = Model.app.datasources.db.connector;
  commons
    .getResultSqlString(conn, sqlEstablecimiento.findIdiomas, [id, nivel]) //and use it there, maybe, depending on what your code is doing?
    .then(stb => {
      cb(null, stb);
    })
    .catch(err => cb(err, null));
  };
```

Comment: _Update_: I didn't see your request URL yesterday in your post, so I hope you guessed the new one should be: *{{url}}/api/idiomas/oferta/{{oferta}}/Inicial* or *{{url}}/api/idiomas/oferta?id={{oferta}}&nivel=Inicial* if you remove the *path* attribute in your *http* argument.